# In Perl, while using RC4 I am unable to get back the encrypted text

Tags: perl, encryption, unpack, rc4-cipher

I have a file with encrypted credentials with RC4,
The piece of code in charge to write such credentials to the file is the following:

```
sub dummyFunction() {
    # Useless stuff for the scope of the problem
    # ...
    my $dbHost = "localhost";
    my $passphrase = "123"; # For example purposes, logic is different.
    my $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new($passphrase);
    return unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4($dbHost));
}
```

So that piece of code would return something like: `3F9FDCE3891C6B8851`
but if I try the following:

```
sub anotherDummyFunction() {
    my $ciphered_text = &dummyFunction();
    my $passphrase = "123";
    my $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new($passphrase);
    print $cipher->RC4(pack('H*',$ciphered_text));
}
```

I am expecting to see `localhost` but instead, I get a bunch of bytes, so how would I get back the original text?

I already checked with a RC4 decryptor online, with my passphrase and my hex encoded string and the RC4 decryptor online does return `localhost` so I am sure that the encrypted string is right.

Thanks!

**P.S.**: The above example works in an isolated environment, but when it comes to my script it doesn't. I cannot get back the original string.

Comment: Don't show us example code that works and tell us that it doesn't work in some other context. The only thing we know is that the problem *isn't* in anything you've shown us.

Comment: I'll use my psychic debugging skills to say that some whitespace has gotten into `$ciphered_text` in your actual script.  `pack('H*',$ciphered_text)` does **not** pack just hexadecimal digits; it grabs the low 4 bits of each character in `$ciphered_text`, including whitespace characters.

Comment: I already found the root of the problem.
At first I thought it was a whitespace, but it wasn't that.
I was encrypting another string right before that one, but that one was being encrypted correctly.
I had an epiphany and I thought that RC4 could be caching stuff, so I undef it, and it worked.

Comment: RC4 is a stream cipher, so of course `$cipher->RC4("encrypt-me")) x 2 ne $cipher->RC4("encrypt-me" x 2))`.  If it were, a Boy Scout with a piece of paper and a pencil could break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this again:

If you have something like:

---

**TEST.PL**

---

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Crypt::RC4;

 my $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new("passphrase123");
 print unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4("encrypt-me"))."\n";
 print unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4("encrypt-me"))."\n";
```

You will notice that you'll end up with two different encoded strings:

```
 ./test.pl
 25d2aa557cccc3951074
 1e87a5db7830a0b1cabd
```

In order to avoid this behavior I did:

`undef $cipher`

Right before trying to encrypt another string, and then instantiated the object again.

If you try this:

```
 my $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new("passphrase123");
 print unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4("encrypt-me"))."\n";
 undef($cipher);
 $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new("passphrase123");
 print unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4("encrypt-me"))."\n";
```

You'll get the same string:

```
./test.pl
25d2aa557cccc3951074
25d2aa557cccc3951074
```

this can also be wrapped in subprocedure, to avoid defining and undefining the object over and over.

```
sub encryptString()
{
    my ($string,$passphrase) = @_;
    my $cipher = Crypt::RC4->new($passphrase);
    return unpack('H*',$cipher->RC4($string));
}
```

Comment: Reading up on this stuff, came across this. A perl note: `undef($cipher);` is an unnecessary distraction. Remove it and the example runs with the same output shown (`25d2aa557cccc3951074` twice). The second `new` call is creating a "clean" `$cipher` so has the same content/output as the first.

Comment: Thanks @Ashley. I remember posting this in my second day of working with Perl. I've learnt so much since then!